# How to define a pyspark schema with an array

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with an infered schema that looks like the below. How would I define this schema in pyspark?

```
root
 |-- active: string (nullable = true)
 |-- activeText: string (nullable = true)
 |-- addOns: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- addOnID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- amount: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- category: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- creditTo: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- productID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- quantity: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- subscriptionID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- taxable: string (nullable = true)
 |-- addedBy: string (nullable = true)
```

I got this far but wasn't sure how to deal with the array.

```
schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("active", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("activeText", StringType(), True),
        ...
        StructField("addedBy", IntegerType(), True),
    ]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check [ArrayType](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-arraytype-column-with-examples/) with examples.

For you case:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("active", StringType(), True),
    StructField("activeText", StringType(), True),
    StructField("addOns", ArrayType(StructType([
        StructField("addOnID", StringType(), True),
        StructField("amount", StringType(), True),
        StructField("category", StringType(), True),
        StructField("code", StringType(), True),
        StructField("creditTo", StringType(), True),
        StructField("description", StringType(), True),
        StructField("productID", StringType(), True),
        StructField("quantity", StringType(), True),
        StructField("subscriptionID", StringType(), True),
        StructField("taxable", StringType(), True)
    ]), True)),
    StructField("addedBy", StringType(), True)
])
```